# How to draw axes (x axis and y axis) for static image (drawn using raster data and canvas) in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-5

How to draw x axis and y axis for the static image in open layers?
Static image is formed using raster data and kept inside canvas and placed as a layer in Map component.
X axis and y axis should zoom according to raster zoom.

Comment: You can show vector lines over your image, for example  https://codesandbox.io/s/static-image-forked-3c4j6

Comment: I want to draw x axis and y axis like chart for static images based on values of raster image.for example x min is 46500 and x max is 558000.then x-axis should be plotted with min and Max values of raster image.please suggest I could not find any where to do this